# spring-cloud-skipper-server - logging in Json format

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, datadog

We recently started using SCDF on Kubernetes, and we are trying to workout the kinks. One of thing things that i was'nt able to find is whether there is a way to affect logging format,for ex. switch to using Json format. Reason for this is simple, we are using Datadog as our logging platform, and with Json, you don't have to write custom log parsing rules.

With regular log format, you will endup with something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow and Skipper servers are `Spring Boot` applications and hence you can configure/customize logging system based on your requirements.

Here are some of the references to configure logging system for a Spring Boot app:

- [Custom log configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration)
- [Logback configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)

Comment: I accept this, but the one part missing here is how to load a external resource to SCDF, like logback.xml that can be than used as a logging configuration

Comment: Also, the problem is that the json layout is not by default on classpath of SCDF, so file only config is not possible

Comment: Hi, You can use the Spring Boot external config via `spring.config.additional-location`

Comment: Yes, but you still wont be able to include a dependency to classpath

Comment: In order to do that you need to have a custom build for SCDF/Skipper. For instance, you can see this custom SCDF build for customizing database config: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-25x

Comment: At the end this was easier to solve by adjusting the parsing rules in DataDot,but im accepting your answer since its true too